# How to iterate over channel and assign as reference

Tags: go, channel

It seems assigning channel output to an array of pointers will always assign the last one sent to the channel `string2`. can anyone explain this behavior?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myType struct {
    myString string
}

func main() {
    queue := make(chan myType, 2)
    queue <- myType{myString: "string1"}
    queue <- myType{myString: "string2"}
    close(queue)

    var types []*myType

    for element := range queue {
        types = append(types, &element)
    }

    for _, element := range types {
        fmt.Println(element.myString)
    }
}
```

results in:

```
result2
result2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with channels. Check this code which has the same result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myType struct {
    myString string
}

func main() {
    in := [2]myType{
        myType{myString: "string1"},
        myType{myString: "string2"},
    }

    var types []*myType

    for _, element := range in {
        types = append(types, &element)
    }

    for _, element := range types {
        fmt.Println(element.myString)
    }
}
```

[Play](https://play.golang.org/p/uf0r4yWmmHD)

The problem is that you're taking a pointer to `element`, a variable which will get a new value each time through the loop, *but the variable itself stays the same*, so all pointers you append to the slice point to the same value. To fix this, append values instead of pointers or create a temorary in your loop and push a pointer to the temporary instead

```
var types []myType

for element := range queue {
    types = append(types, element)
}
```

or

```
var types []*myType

for element := range queue {
    tmp := element
    types = append(types, &tmp)
}
```